# Finite number of T-invariant subspaces iff the restriction has a finite number of T-invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a finite vector space over a field $F$ and let $T\in \mathcal L({V})$ an operator.

$p_m=p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_n^{r_n}$ the minimal polynomial of $T$ and $W_i=\ker(p_i^{r_i}(T))$

$V=\displaystyle \bigoplus_{i=1}^nW_i $ $\hspace{0.4cm}$ by the primary decomposition theorem.

Show that $T$ has a finite number of $T$-invariant subspaces iff $T|_{W_j}$
has a finite number of T-invariant subspaces for every $1 \leq j \leq n$

I was trying to prove it without using cyclic vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check that the $W_i$ are $T$-invariant subspaces.
- Check that if $S$ is a $T$-invariant subspace, then so is $S \cap W_i$.

---

Suppose there are finitely many $T$-invariant subspaces $S_1, \ldots, S_m$ of $V$. Then $S_1 \cap W_i, \ldots, S_m \cap W_i$ are the $T|_{W_j}$-invariant subspaces of $W_j$ (possibly with repeats).

---

If $S$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, then check that
$$S = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n (S \cap W_i).$$
If each $W_i$ has finitely many $T|_{W_j}$-invariant subspaces, what does that say about the number of $T$-invariant subspaces of $V$?

Comment: We know that $S$ and $W_i$ are $T$-invariant, so $S\cap W_i$ has to be $T$-invariant but if we have a finite number of subspaces such that $T|_{W_i}$ is $T$-invariant, then we have a finite number of subspaces such that $T|_{S \cap W_i}$ is $T$-invariant, therefore by the above equality we have a finite number of $T$-invariant subspaces. Is it correct? I had already checked the first two statements and the equality that is a corollary of the primary decomposition theorem